# Select All Choices in Jenkins Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, selected

I want to select all the choices in my Groovy script so it defaults to all.  I am using the Active Choices Reactive Parameter because I am reading in the previous option.  How do I make my "output" variable so it is all selected without having the user select them all?

```
def output = []
def line
def release = RELEASE_NUMBER
releaseNumber = release.replaceAll("\\n", "");
String[] number = releaseNumber.split("\\.");

def list = "cmd /c e:\\tools\\wget --no-check-certificate --http-user=username--http-password=password-qO- \"https://1.1.1.1:443/svn/Instructions/trunk/${number[0]}.${number[1]}.${number[2]}/ICAN/EI_${releaseNumber}.txt\"".execute().text
list.eachLine {
     if (it.contains("- LH")) {
         String newName = it.replaceAll("\\s", "");
         String newName2 = newName.replaceAll("-", "");
         output.add(newName2)
     }
}
return output
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know anything about Jenkins, but reading [the documentation for the plugin you mention](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) you should be able to simply use `output.add("${newName2}:selected")`.

Comment: Well, glad it helped. Could you accept the answer then ?